# targeting an element after changing class attribute is not working

Tags: jquery, dom, click

I'm trying to target an element loaded with the dom and when clicking it changes it's class and after clicking on the same item with the new class it should alert but the alert shows up after the first click with the old class

html

```
<div class="top_favorites">
<a href="#" class="addToFav">click</a>
</div>
```

js inside document ready

```
$("a.addToFav").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).attr("class","addedToFav")
});

$(".top_favorites").on("click","a.addedToFav",function(e){
    alert("fdgdfd");
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).attr("class","addToFav")
});
```

live code http://jsfiddle.net/p6s0oac4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click event bubbles up, so after the class is changed your second click event handler is executed too.

The code below will work and is more consistent:

```
$(".top_favorites").on("click","a.addToFav",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).attr("class","addedToFav")
});

$(".top_favorites").on("click","a.addedToFav",function(e){
    alert("fdgdfd");
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).attr("class","addToFav")
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/p6s0oac4/1/